# Noise in opamp amplifiying circuit which can be removed by short-circuiting VDDA and GNDA?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, oscillator, short-circuit, stable

I have built a filtering and amplifying circuit for an ultrasonic receiving channel. The schematic is shown as below. The +3.3V is the power supply of a microcontroller.
[image]
It amplifies the receiving signal around 42 kHz and level-shifts it to be centered at 1.65V.

Problem is sometimes the noise floor increases more than 100%. The extra noise floor appears randomly after each power on/off. Interestingly, it can be removed by shortly short-circuiting the +3.3VA and the GNDA (using tweezers). After that the circuit can work properly for quite a long time (>24 hours), at least I have not encountered the case the extra noise appears later after a clean start.

I guess this extra noise is a self-oscillating of the opamps. Can someone give me some suggestions about how to make this circuit more robust?

Comment: Do you mean that the 3.3V is also the supply of the micro? Because if so then it sounds like you are power cycling the microcontroller. Perhaps it is entering a state in which it puts a lot of noise on to the power rails?

Comment: @loudnoises, Yes the 3.3V also powers the microcontroller, however, 1. there is a bead between 3.3V and 3.3VA; 2. after rebooting (both normal power on/off and short-circuiting by tweezers) the microcontroller does nothing, it just waits for commands. In addition, I have tried to reset the microcontroller by pulling down its reset pin when there was the extra noise, the noise remained after reseting.

Comment: Yes, L19 would not stop you from shorting the power supply. (1) How frequently have you seen this happen? (2) Can you capture the noise, and if so is it visible on 3.3VA?